# htaccess: redirect to last slash if not use '&' or '?'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want redirect all links to last `/`

But if use `?` or `&` in URL, i want no redirect

> Sample :

```
http://name.com/page => http://name.com/page/ // Redirect
http://name.com/hello/new => http://name.com/hello/new/ // Redirect
http://name.com/hello/?text=yes => http://name.com/hello/?text=yes // NO Redirect
http://name.com/other/?text=yes&val=ok => http://name.com/other/?text=yes&val=ok // NO Redirect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
# add a trailing slash if not real files and no query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: i want if file format is "xml" not redirect, how i can ? thank you

Comment: Just add another condition as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$ [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On

# checking empty query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.xml !-f
RewriteEngine ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i want if file format is "xml" not redirect, how i can ? thank you

Comment: Thank yout. this code not work : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.xml !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: I hope you are not mixing the rules, Use my rules for checking.

Comment: is it not redirecting with '/' you are saying.